The bathroom sink drips water onto the cabinet after use
I have the same problem with three sinks in two bedrooms at home. Water starts seeping out from next to the white gasket after washing, but I'm not sure what material it is made of (concrete?) One of them has a hole, but the other two don't, how can I fix it?





can you point on the picture, where is it leaking

@Traveler sounds to me like it's leaking from the white plastic nut on the bottom of the faucet—which probably really means it's leaking from the faucet valve.

You may have a poor seal between the base of the faucet and the sink.  Water is splashed there and finds its'  way out the hole on the underside of the sink.
